# Is there a high-level PDF report generator for GTK+/cairo like scribe for Qt?

Tags: pdf, gtk, pygtk, cairo

I'd like my (Py)Gtk+ (and hence cairo/pango) based program to generate PDF output. I know that for Qt there is [Scribe](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/richtext.html) which I believe allows high-level report generation (i.e. on a logical document layout level, e.g. headings, paragraphs, lists etc). Now cairo and pango are rather low-level, so I was wondering if there was any cairo/pango based equivalent to Scribe?